# Add an UIView over my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints, xib

I'm trying to add a custom UIView over my UITableView displaying current time. I don't know exactly how to do it.
I have added this view to tableview in xib file and top margin constraints programmatically to change its position each minute but it stays on top. I think the view is added as header to the tableview and that isn't what I want.

|- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - |
|  1 ----------------------------  |

|  2 ----------------------------  |

|  3 ----------------------------  |
.
.
.
|  13 ---------------------------  |
|**13:33 - - - - - - - - - - - - - -** |
|  14 ---------------------------  |

|  15 ---------------------------  |
.
.
.
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|

It would be something like this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want that the UIView stays at fixed position over UITableView?

Comment: I want to scroll the tableview and view scrolls with it. So it is fixed to tableview content view.

Comment: Can you place the UIView in the UITableView cell then?

Comment: Why you are adding it in scroll view, You can just add it viewcontroller view on same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better will be add that view in supperview of tablview view... means  parent of both tableview and view should be one... Then bring your view on front. You can do this by code as well as by interfacebuilder.

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:oneofchildView];
```

In Interface builder you just have to drop your view after the tableView

Comment: I've tried to put both views within a UIScrollView at same level, but UIView doesn't scroll. Do you know what could I be doing wrong?? Thanks

Comment: I finally figured out how to fix it. I added both, custom UIView and UITableView within a UIView which it's UIScrollView content size. Thanks everybody for the help

Comment: how to do if u are using prototype cells in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

create a UIView programatically and add that UIView object to tableView

ex:

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc]initwithframe:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[self.tableView addSubView:overlayView];
```

try this it might helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView *myOverlayView = [[UIView alloc]initwithframe:yourframe];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myOverlayView];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just dragged your view onto your tableview that's the most likely think to happen. Add it as subview to your view.
Also for that you have to quit using UITableViewController since it has table as it's root view